# using vba code, add records to detail section of existing report

Tags: vba, adodb

I'm trying to add records to detail section of existing report. The data shows up in design view but not on the report. The report shows blank fields. Also if I want each field to have a black border, how do I do this in vba code Below is my code:
    Dim stDocName As String
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim rs2 As Recordset
    Dim sSQL As String
    Dim fld As DAO.Field ' recordset field
    Dim txtNew As Access.TextBox ' textbox control
    Dim rpt As Report ' hold report object
    Dim lngTop As Long ' holds top value of control position
    Dim lngLeft As Long ' holds left value of controls position
    Dim location As Long

```
' initialise position variables
lngLeft = 0
lngTop = 0

'Create the report
'Set rpt = CreateReport

stDocName = "rptInvoice"
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acViewDesign

sSQL = "Select SOWCode, SowDescription, Qty, Rate, SOWTotal from tbltmpInvoice"

' set properties of the Report
```

'    With rpt
'        .Width = 8500
'        .RecordSource = sSQL
'    End With

```
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL)

'Count all records in the table tblCompany
rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst

location = location + 900
```

Read_Records:

```
' Create corresponding label and text box controls for each field.
For Each fld In rs.Fields

    ' Create new text box control and size to fit data.
    Set txtNew = CreateReportControl(stDocName, acTextBox, _
    acDetail, , fld.Value, location, lngTop)
    'txtNew.SizeToFit

    'Relocate text field
    location = location + 1000

Next

DoCmd.Close

' Increment top value for next control
'lngTop = lngTop + txtNew.Height + 25

stDocName = "rptInvoice"
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acViewPreview

'DoCmd.Close
```

Comment: You should reformat your question, some of the code appears as text.